# Integral involving linear function of bounds

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a nondecreasing function. Show that if $\int_a^{a+1} f(x) \mathrm dx$ and $\int_{a+1}^{a+2022} f(x) \mathrm dx$ are linear functions of $a$ then $f(x)$ is a linear function.

Hi, I can see this is obviously true for any polynomial $f(x)$, but am unsure on how to proceed. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts and to provide the source of this problem.  Tests and contest problems often reference the current year.

Comment: Hi, I do not know the source of this problem as a teacher has given me this question